# JSONException , JSONObject exception Error

Tags: java, android, json, jsonexception

Description: In OnRespose method i can see data received from froecast.io  in log  but when i am passing "response.body().string()" i.e. data from forecast.io as argument(string) to method getCurrentDetails then Method is receiving null and JSONObject is throwing null pointer Exception.

Tried: handle exception through multiple catch block.

```
    double latitude = -122.423;
    double longitude = 37.8267;
    String apiKey = "cac63237c81f5312b496ed8cce991b40";
    String forecastURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+apiKey+"/"+longitude+","+latitude+"";
    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(forecastURL).build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mCurrentWeather  = getCurrentDetails(response.body().string());

                    } else {
                        alertUserAboutProblem();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught: ", e);
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Exception Caught: ", e);
                }
            }
        });

        Log.e(TAG, "Program is still running");
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Network_Unavaliable",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}

private CurrentWeather getCurrentDetails(String string) throws JSONException {
```

------>>>>>  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
        String timezone = jsonObject.getString("timezone");

```
    JSONObject currently =jsonObject.getJSONObject("currently");

    CurrentWeather currentWeather = new CurrentWeather();

    currentWeather.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
    currentWeather.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
    currentWeather.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
    currentWeather.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
    currentWeather.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
    currentWeather.setPrecipIntensity(currently.getDouble("percipIntensity"));
    currentWeather.setTimeZone(timezone);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(currently.getLong("time")),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(currentWeather.getTime()));
    return currentWeather;
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo coninfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if(coninfo!=null && coninfo.isConnected()){
        isAvailable = true;
        return isAvailable;
    }

    return false;
}

private void alertUserAboutProblem() {

    AlertDialogFragment dialog =new AlertDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),TAG);
}
```

}

Comment: so where is your NPE thrown? and what does your JSON look like?

Comment: Make sure, before you get any value from jsonObject, check json Object is not null and the property that you are trying to read exists, using jsonObject.has("your property"). Other than this, from the data that you have given, I could come only to this conclusion. IF you could print the json value that you are passing, it will be of great help in debugging.

Comment: NPE is thrown when I am creating JSONObject I have marked that line with arrow. My json is weather data recieving from forecast.io.

Comment: check whether you are really receiving the response data(json). @Santhana said log your json response.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving response.body().string() to a String variable and then passing it to getCurrentDetails.

Per the [documentation](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Response.html): "the response body is a one-shot value that may be consumed only once".